# Install SSL like Certbot in a Hostinger's VPS without NGINX for Odoo

Tags: nginx, ssl, odoo, vps

I am trying to install an ssl certificate with certbot on a hostinger vps for an odoo. This vps does not have nginx, which is what I usually see installed in the tutorials. Nor can I understand myself with the distribution that they have in the vps hostinger. On the part of hostinger they do not offer me help because, in their words "They specialize in hosting websites and their help with vps development is limited." Any help please?

I have tried to install the ssl certificate using the hostinger tools but they have not let me since they are oriented to the cyber panel and not to other applications.

I tried to get into the server and install the universe and ppa:certbot/certbot repositories but I couldn't get them to download.

I tried to find the odoo folder to put a file with a certificate there, but the only odoo folder I could find is one where there is only one configuration file and I'm not sure if putting it there would work.

Answer (score 1):

In a VPS you have to do pretty much everything by yourself. So you could do whatever you want. Connect to it using SSH and install Nginx, Certbot or what you like to do accomplish your goals. Seems you are not very familiar with DevOps and you are trying to do it by yourself. You could follow a tutorial about how to install the specific Odoo version for the specific Server operating system... Or hire someone to do it for you